# What dimensions should i change to solve this?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I building a CNN model, an having trouble with the dimensions.

```
src = Input(shape=(196,41,3))

conv11 = Conv2D(32, kernel_size=4, activation='relu')(src)

pool11 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv11)

conv12 = Conv2D(16, kernel_size=4, activation='relu')(pool11)

drop = Dropout(0.3)

pool12 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv12)

flat1 = Flatten()(pool12)

# second input model
trgt = Input(shape=(196,41,3))
conv21 = Conv2D(32, kernel_size=4, activation='relu')(trgt)

pool21 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv21)

conv22 = Conv2D(16, kernel_size=4, activation='relu')(pool21)

pool22 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv22)

flat2 = Flatten()(pool22)
# merge input models
merge = keras.layers.concatenate([flat1, flat2])

# interpretation model
hidden1 = Dense(64, activation='relu')(merge)
output = Dense(196, activation='relu')(hidden1)

arch = Model(inputs=[src, trgt], outputs=output)
```

I am getting this

Error when checking target: expected dense_35 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (70, 41, 196, 3)

Comment: Your output neurons should be the number of classes. Do you really have 196 different classes?

Comment: I'm not aiming for classes, the model is having 2 input pictures and outputs 1 with features of both input images. so its more of a regression problem pixels wise than classifying.

Comment: which line you got error? Please provide the full traceback code.

Comment: It looks good to me for the current code you provide.